# how to configure the tomcat bundled with maven?

Tags: eclipse, maven, tomcat, jakarta-ee

I know that maven has its own tomcat plugin, so there is no need to install tomcat, but after newing a project,the index.jsp file reports "The superclass 'javax.servlet.ttp.HttpServlet' was not found on the java Build Path", which I believe a server configuration problem.

My question is: how to configure the tomcat (bundled with maven)?

Comment: Are you sure you're not starting from a false premise?

Comment: javax.servlet.ttp.HttpServlet - shouldnˋt that be javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet?